# NativeScript with Angular but without Router possible?

Tags: angular, nativescript, router

Is it possible to use **NativeScript with Angular but without the router** so navigation is done like it is in NativeScript Core with frames? Are there any examples / templates?

Reason: the router available with NativeScript with Angular seems quite restrictive to me, e.g. requiring child routes in case of modals with navigation (modals with navigation are now supported by NativeScript 4.1 with Angular). Also it seems to sometimes non-deterministically break when using modals with navigation (e.g. refer to [NativeScript 4.1 with Angular: Modal view with navigation may result in router issues so some pages can no longer be shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812037/nativescript-4-1-with-angular-modal-view-with-navigation-may-result-in-router-i)).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use frame navigation without an issue.

Comment: Could you point me to any example how one can navigate using frame and without router to a page defined with Angular? That would be great.